# Apply same query on different data, output is not as expected

Tags: database, postgresql, query-optimization

I have two tables, N and G. Both tables have similar structures, N has much more records than G has.  I applied same query on this two tables separately and explain analyze returned different results: It takes much longer time for the query to run on the smaller table, which is out of my expectatoin. I thought it should take less time on small table for sure. I attached the parts that are different and hope someone can help me check what caused this problem and how I can improve. Thank you!

On table G (less records):

```
CTE records    
     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..23.37 rows=9 width=163) (actual     time=13.584..1570.833 rows=176 loops=1)      
           Buffers: shared hit=149481      
           ->  CTE Scan on pairs  (cost=0.00..0.18 rows=9 width=128) (actual time=13.569..1569.781 rows=176 loops=1)       
                 Buffers: shared hit=148953    
           ->  Index Scan using ix_station_icao on station  (cost=0.28..2.57 rows=1 width=67) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=176)      
                 Index Cond: (icao = pairs.siteid)     
                 Buffers: shared hit=528       

   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.66..0.84 rows=9 width=74) (actual  time=1571.302..1571.313 rows=15 loops=1)      
         Buffers: shared hit=149481    
         ->  Sort  (cost=0.66..0.68 rows=9 width=74) (actual time=1571.297..1571.300 rows=15 loops=1)      
               Sort Key: records.observed_contingency_row, records.forecast_contingency_col    
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB    
               Buffers: shared hit=149481      
               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.43..0.52 rows=9 width=74) (actual time=1571.282..1571.282 rows=15 loops=1)       
                     Group Key: records.source, records.siteid, records.observed_contingency_row, records.forecast_contingency_col     
                     Buffers: shared hit=149481     

                     ->  CTE Scan on records  (cost=0.00..0.18 rows=9 width=74) (actual time=13.588..1570.983 rows=176 loops=1)    
                           Buffers: shared hit=149481      
 Planning time: 7.656 ms       
 Execution time: 1571.584 ms
```

On table N (more records):

```
   CTE records
     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..2.73 rows=1 width=163) (actual time=2.830..8.669 rows=176 loops=1)
           Buffers: shared hit=2221
           ->  CTE Scan on pairs  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=128) (actual time=2.815..7.833 rows=176 loops=1)
                 Buffers: shared hit=1693
           ->  Index Scan using ix_station_icao on station  (cost=0.28..2.70 rows=1 width=67) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=176)
                 Index Cond: (icao = pairs.siteid)
                 Buffers: shared hit=528

   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.08..0.11 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=9.473..9.485 rows=14 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=2221
         ->  Sort  (cost=0.08..0.09 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=9.468..9.470 rows=14 loops=1)
               Sort Key: records.observed_contingency_row, records.forecast_contingency_col
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
               Buffers: shared hit=2221
               ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.03..0.07 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=9.365..9.462 rows=14 loops=1)
                     Group Key: records.source, records.siteid, records.observed_contingency_row, records.forecast_contingency_col
                     Buffers: shared hit=2221
                     ->  Sort  (cost=0.03..0.04 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=9.354..9.363 rows=176 loops=1)
                           Sort Key: records.source, records.siteid, records.observed_contingency_row, records.forecast_contingency_col
                           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 38kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=2221

                           ->  CTE Scan on records  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=2.833..8.853 rows=176 loops=1)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=2221
 Planning time: 4.987 ms
 Execution time: 9.732 ms
```

(74 rows)

Thank you

Comment: [I cannot tell from here, without actual DDL & table contents] The problem is probably caused by the CTE (two CTEs?) CTE's are hard to estimate, and hard to fit into the plan. If you want to optimize: remove the CTE's (rewrite to JOINs. [IMHO]

Comment: I think you are right. I tried to write CTE into real tables, then the difference disappear. I will see what I can do from here. Thank you